# Auto click like buttons on my Feed Instagram directly from Google Chrome's DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, instagram

The button path is:

[image]

The auto click I tried in the DevTools Console was:

```
document.querySelectorAll('svg[aria-label="Curtir"]').forEach(btn => btn.click());
```

The error when trying to run:

```
Uncaught TypeError: btn.click is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:74
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:55
```

Usually on websites this model for clicks works fine, but for Instagram it's not working, what am I doing wrong so that the result is not positive?

Comment: Could you try `document.querySelectorAll('svg[aria-label="Curtir"]').forEach(btn => btn.closest("button").click());` ?

Comment: Hello friend @Philippe , thank you very much for the indication and it solved the problem perfectly, could you create an answer so that I can mark it as a solution and close the question? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Glad to read it :) I've just posted an answer. Happy coding !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `svg` elements themselves are not clickable.

```
document.querySelectorAll('svg[aria-label="Curtir"]').forEach(svg => svg.closest("button").click());
```

should work :)